# Div with constant proportions and always 100% of screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create div which would behave in a following way:

1. it would always resize his height to 100% of browser window height.
2. it will adjust his width to maintain constant proportions (so that his width would be allays equal to 3/5 of his height for an instance)

There are some examples here which do opposite thing - maintain width at some fixed % value of browser window size, and adjust height accordingly but its not what i need.

Comment: I recommend you to try first, and then post your code here if it doesn't work as it is expected

Comment: It works as expected but it doesnt meet my expectations. If width is set to fit screen and height to adjust accordingly to predefined proportions in wide-screens my site will not fit to screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#resizable').width($('#resizable').height()*3/5);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Demo:

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#resizable').width($('#resizable').height()*3/5);
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

```css
html,body,#resizable{
    height:100%;
}
#resizable{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resizable"></div>
```

Comment: @Czulu you r welcome.BTW if my answer helped you accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I use jquery here:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  var el_height = $(element).height(window.innerHeight);
  $(element).width((el_height*3)/5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is get the height of the browser window with jQuery and set the width of the div accordingly.

```
function changeDivSize(){
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    var newDivWidth = height * 0.6;
    $("#divId").height(wHeight);
    $("#divId").width(newDivWidth);
};
$(document).ready(changeDivSize);
$(window).resize(changeDivSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

i was going to support Nocky Tellekamp's answer but it misses couple of things :

first, in order to get window Hieght in cross browser you need to use `$(window).innerHeight();`

Proper code view :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var WindowHeight = $(window).innerHeight(); //$(window).height() not working in I.E and part of other wierd browsers not based on mozila engine
    $("#divId").css {            //proper and more orgenized code view of css changing
         hieght : WindowHeight,
         width : WindowHieght * 0.6
    };
```

});

```
you dont have to call method on window.resize (causes very bad performance issue if bigger algorithem involved), if it does bother's you, i would suggest to use different css properties such as clear:both when setting the div so actually it will spread on the entire window height and width.
```